# How to represent numerically the diversity of groups of datapoints with a single value?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, diversity

I work for a performing arts organization, and am trying to create a numerical figure to represent the amount of genre-diversity in each of our seasons. So let's say that we have a Spring Season and a Fall Season.

There may be 5 theater events in Spring, 3 music events, and 6 art exhibitions.
And 6 theater events in Fall, 5 music events, and 5 art exhibitions.

My thought is to--for each season--find the total number of events, the proportion of each genre that makes up that total in percentage, and subtract those percentages from one another, add the absolute value of the difference, and then the higher that number is, the less evenly distributed the season would be right?

The more variant the percentages are the less evenly distributed the events are, and thus one is probably getting more events than another.

My main question is what is the statistical vocabulary to describe this (if it's something that would work anyway)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe resembles the sum of absolute deviations (https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Average_absolute_deviation), except that you propose to add up absolute differences between pairs of points, while deviations are defined as differences from the mean. Both work, the main difference being perhaps that your proposition would produce more "dramatic" results, as each deviation from a balanced proportion is added up multiple times through the multiple pairwise differences.

Comment: Thanks friend! @Ous

Answer (score 1):

The information criterion used in Decision Tree Model might fit your problem. See [Decision Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning)

For example, the entropy criterion

$ \sum{-p_i log(p_i)} $ where $p_i =$ portion of i- category

describes the diversity of a group. When the group is pure (everything belong to 1 category), the entropy is 0, when there are more categories and diversity in a group, the value of entropy will increase.

The similar description also true for gini impurity $ 1- \sum{p_i^2}$ and some other more metrics.